# Laravel use external class

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, lamp

I'm new on laravel and need some help.
Actualy i use 5.3 laravel version.
I need to use, in laravel, external company framework (call it F for semplicity).
This framework is some like process manager. Actualy, for integrate it with laravel i put it in laravel/public folder, this way i can use laravel and F's pages in same domain. In laravel i need to access to some F functionality wich is all collect in class FFramework\Facade\FInterface; 
Then i want to acces to this class from laravel controller FController.
But when i run code i get Class Not Found Exception.

### This is folder structure:

- laravel

  - app

    - http

      - controllers
      - FController.php
- public

  - css
  - js
  - index.php
  - fframework

    - facade

      - FInterface.php
    - index.php

### This is code example:

FController.php

```
<?php
  namespace App\Http\Controllers;

  use FFramework\facade\FInterface;

  class FController extends Controller {

      public function getSimpleDAta() {
          $f = new FInterface();
          return $f->getSimpleData();
    }
  }
```

FInterface.php

```
<?php
  namespace FFramework\facade;

  use some\internal\function;

  class FInterface {

      public function getSimpleDAta() {
          $simpleData = ...omg so much computation :) ...
          return $simpleData;
    }
  }
```

### Exception that i get:

Class 'FFramework\facade\FInterface' not found

### Additional Information

I use standard LAMP configuration
PHP version is last 5.6 stable version

### Question

How can i use FInterface from Laravel controller leaving FFramework in public folder?

Comment: Laravel uses composer's autoloader, add the namespace and path to the autoload section in composer.json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the autoload section of your `composer.json` file to tell your project where to look for files in the `FFramework` namespace.

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
        "FFramework\\": "public/fframework"
    }
},
```